# Using package.json script to run another package.json script

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I have a `package.json` script for example `npm run script1` and I have also private npm package which is added as a dependency in my project and this package has also scripts in `package.json` and this script name `script2`. I want that when I run `npm run script1` then run automatically start script2. Is that possible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [npm explore](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/explore) command. For example, to run a test script from lodash after running eslint, add this script in your package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "script1": "eslint . && npm explore lodash -- npm run test"
}
```

Then run it as:

```
npm run script1
```

Comment: This looks pretty useful. Does `yarn` has any similar alternative?

Comment: @GanapatiVS I haven't used yarn myself but I have read that in yarn, you can use "cwd" option to run scripts from other module.

Answer (score 9):

**Package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "runbothscripts": "npm run script1 && npm run script2"
}
```

Should run both scripts for you if you execute it by doing `npm run runbothscripts`.

If `script2` would be in a different folders package.json you also first navigate to that folder by doing `cd ./otherfolder && npm run script2`

Comment: Can you navigate to the folder by adding `cd ./node_modules/insertpackagenamehere && npm run script2` ? But I would recommend trying @harsh989 's approach with npm explore first